# Proving $X/ \sim$ is Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $X$ is a topological space. Suppose there is an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $X$ where $x \sim y$ iff for any Hausdorff space $Y$ and every continuous map $f:X \rightarrow Y$ it holds that $f(x) = f(y)$. Define $X_H = X / \sim$ and equip it with the quotient topology. Suppose $\pi_H:X \rightarrow X_H$ is the canonical projection map.

I was able to prove that for for any Hausdorff space $Y$ and every continuous map $f:X \rightarrow Y$ it holds that there is a unique continuous function $f_H : X_H \rightarrow Y$ such that $f=f_H \circ \pi_H$.

I now want to prove that $X_H$ is a Hausdorff space. For this I thought that since $f_H$ is a unique continuous function and $Y$ is Hausdorff that this would complete the proof. So my question is: is it enough to say that since $f_H$ is continuous and $Y$ is Hausdorff that $X_H$ must be Hausdorff?

Maybe $f_H$ should be surjective?

Comment: No, it's not enough. Also, $f_H$ is surjective iff $f$ is.

Comment: @Berci Would you be able to explain a little bit more? does it hold for any continuous function $f:X \rightarrow Y$ that if $Y$ is Hausdorff then $X$ is too?

Comment: It doesn't hold, only if $f$ is injective.

Comment: So how is $f_H$ injective here?

Comment: It isn't necessarily injective.

Comment: You need another method. See e.g. the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $x\neq y\in X_{H}\implies$ that $x,y$ are not related in $X$.

So there exist a pair $(Y,f)$ such that $Y$ is Hausdorff and $f$ is continuous from $X\to Y$ such that $f(x)\neq f(y)$.

So we take disjoint open  nbds $U$, $V$ of $f(x),f(y)$ in $Y$.

Then $\bar{U}=\bar{f}^{-1}(U)$ and $\bar{V}=\bar{f}^{-1}(V)$ are  open nbds of $x$ and $y$ in $X_{H}$ which are disjoint ,where $\bar{f}$ is such that $\bar{f}\circ \pi=f$

Comment: How is this different from '$f:X\rightarrow Y$ continuous and $Y$ Hausdorff, then $X$ Hausdorff' ? This doesn't hold as Berci pointed out above, but I don't see the difference of what this answer boils down to and the false statement?

Comment: @Geigercounter This proof potentially uses a lot of Hausdorff spaces $Y$: one for each distinct pair $x,y\in X_H$. Whereas your argument seems to utilize only one such $Y$.

Comment: @Geigercounter As berci points out, you need to use all the assumptions in the question.  You are not only restricting to just one such $Y$ but also to one such $f$. Now take $X$ with indiscrete topology and $Y$ with any Hausdorff topology then a constant function is always continuous but $X$ is not Hausdorff. Just follow the definition of Hausdorffness, take two distinct points , figure out what distinct means in the context, try and find disjoint open sets using the assumptions given in the question.

Comment: I don't see why it doesn't just boil down to '$\bar{f}$ is continuous and $Y$ is Hausdorff so $X_H$ is Hausdorff'. Which is incorrect according to you. In my first comment under this answer I was referring to a general setting, $f$ was just meant to be a continuous function, but in this case it would be your $\bar{f}$.

Comment: $f$ and $\bar{f}$ are not unrelated. $\bar{f}$ is the function through which $f$ "factors through" or which $f$ descends to to give a unqiue map from the quotient space. There is as much one can do to make another person "see it" . Berci already pointed it out that the statement which you are repeating again and again is incorrect and I too gave an explicit counter example.  Ask yourself again , how can a correct statement boil down to an incorrect statement?. You are given a particular relation and you are asked to show something. How can you show it without using all assumptions ?

Comment: @Geigercounter What you are doing again and again is that you are fixing one space $Y$ and one continuous map $f$. Now if you are to conclude about the hausdorffness about $X_{H}$ you can say nothing as the relation which generates $X_{H}$ says that it has to hold for all spaces $Y$ and all continuous $f$. If you instead fixed a $Y$ and a continuous function $f$ and said that $x\sim y$ iff $f(x)=f(y)$ then you could have worked with only one space. However in this case you cannot conclude anything unless more information is given about $f$.

Comment: For example if such an $f$ was not onto(say a constant map) then $X_{H}$ need not be Hausdorff as I pointed it out. Instead if you were given that $f$ is $one-one$ . Then you can say that $x\neq y\implies f(x)\neq f(y)$ and then take the inverse images UNDER $\bar{f}$ as I did. When you are working with quotients given by a relation $\sim$ . Then you have to respect it's assumptions. You cannot just change it as you want and conclude.